# Group Action of $(F - \{0\},\times)$ on a vector space $V$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a very short question, and I apologize if it is a duplicate; I searched for a question like this just in case, but got no results. Exercise 7 of Chapter 1, Section 7 in Dummit and Foote's text reads

> 7. Prove that in Example 2 in this section the action is faithful.

and Example 2 reads

> (2) The axioms for a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ include the two axioms that the multiplicative group $F^\times$ act on the set $V$. ... In the special case when $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $F = \mathbb{R}$ the action is specified by...

where I replaced unimportant sentences with ellipses. Is this exercise asking us to show that the action of $\mathbb{R}^\times$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is faithful? Or the more general statement that $F^\times$ acts faithfully on $V$, where $F$ is any field and $V$ is any vector space over $F$? I'm thinking it is the former, since if $F$ is a field with more than two elements and $V$ is the zero vector space, then $F^\times$ does not act faithfully on $V$ (every element of $F^\times$ induces the identity permutation on $V$!). If I am mistaken, I would appreciate any guidance! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, but if $V$ is the zero vector space (which has no non-zero vectors), then this is not true, as I stated in the last part of the question. Hence, my question.

Comment: It's true in general when $V$ contains an element $x \neq 0$. It's not true for $\Bbb{R}^n$, when $n = 0$. By the way, it is usual to require $1 \neq 0$ in a field, so there is no field with one element.

Comment: @RobArthan Yea, that was my observation. If $V$ is forced to contain a non-zero element, then obviously, the action of $F^\times$ will be faithful. It seems that this exercise was not well-written. I'll just answer a modified version of the exercise (i.e., action of $F^\times$ on $V$ is faithful iff $V$ is not the zero vector space).

Comment: I would say it's easy rather than completely obvious (the analogous statement for modules over a ring is false).

Comment: I forgot one case while writing my comment, so modify the exercise to "action of $F^\times$ on $V$ is faithful iff $V$ is not the zero vector space or $F$ has only $2$ elements".